# what is this colon in jquery after src?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering anyone can explain this one line in the code for me.

```
        $(this).bind('click', {src: $(this).attr('href')}, function (e){
           //commented out since it's irrelevant                    
        });
```

Here is how I understand it:

Bind a function to $(this)'s click event. Also the e parameter is passed to the function too. However it's the middle part that doesn't make sense to me

```
                     {src: $(this).attr('href')}
```

What does this do? I tried google'ing what colon does in jquery. However I get the li:first results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's javascript object notation:

```
var object = {propertyName : propertyValue};
```

It describes an object [literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: to specify what {src: $(this).attr('href')} is...
i believe it is returning to you the value of the clicked links href. this would give you a url most likely.
You would access this by using dot notation obj.src would give you the link

Comment: @axrwkr this creates a new object with a new set of properties.. If you mean as far as the event data, it gets stored on the `eventObject.data` property to avoid those kinds of issues.

Answer (score 5):

`{src: $(this).attr('href')}` is an object literal, you are passing an object into the `.bind` function as the second parameter. Doing so passes said data into the event handler where you can access it when the event happens using `event.data.src` or, `e.data.src` in your case since use used `function (e)...`

Answer (score 3):

That's the way you define an object ( called an object literal ). For example if:

```
obj = { src: "Source" };
```

then obj.src would contain "Source".

Answer (score 2):

You're supplying an inline object with a property src. src has a value of `$(this).attr('href');` The reason you're not able to find jquery specific documentation is that this is a convention that exists in javascript itself.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs for bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), second argument:

```
eventData
    Type: Object
    An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.
```

So, you're passing an object.  The `src:` syntax means a member of that object whose name is `src`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just aditional information to be passed to the callback, in the event object, and can be accessed using:

```
// callback function
function(e){ 
    alert(e.data.src);
}
```